# How do I change the font color on every other row in an excel spreadsheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I need to change every other row's text color to a different color.  I know how to loop through each row, but I don't know how to change the font color of the current cell. How do I do that?

I see how to change the font color on each individual cell, but how do I loop through and do it to many cells?

```
def open_excel_file(file_name,worksheet_name):
    wb = load_workbook(file_name)
    ws = wb[worksheet_name]
    row_count = ws.max_row

    for x in range(1, row_count):
        print(x, ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value)


open_excel_file('craigslist.xlsx', 'motorcycle')
```

Comment: Use the Modulus operator. i.e. `if not i % 2: fill_cell_with_color()`

Comment: Have you read the documentation about styling cells in openpyxl?

Comment: Thanks Henry that got me pointed in the right path, and Charlie I hadn't fully read the documentation as I am still trying to figure out how to understand documentation because I'm fairly new to this.  With a little research though I have found and posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Henry Yik and Charlie Clark above I came up with this as a solution. Thanks Guys

```
def open_excel_file(file_name,worksheet_name):
    wb = load_workbook(file_name)
    ws = wb[worksheet_name]
    row_count = ws.max_row

    for x in range(1, row_count):
        c = ws.cell(row=x, column=1)
        if x % 2 != 0:
            c.font = Font(size=12, color=RED)
    wb.save(file_name)


open_excel_file('craigslist.xlsx', 'motorcycle')
```